# How change color from control page in panorama page using coding4fun color picker

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, binding, user-controls, background-color

Hi. I use this [ColorPicker](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/coding4fun-colorpicker-in-depth). I have first control page (`Popup`) and second main page(`panorama page`). Now I want pickup color via `ColorPicker` in control page and set brush color etc for some element (for example grid background color) in main page. But I dont know how I can bind color from control page to main page (`panorama page`). Any idea or link for example, Thx.

In control Popup `.xaml` I have:

```
<c4fToolkit:ColorPicker x:Name="picker" Height="180" Width="450" ColorChanged="picker_ColorChanged" />
```

In control `Popup.cs` I have:

```
public Brush myColor { get; set; }

public MondayPopup()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}


private void picker_ColorChanged(object sender, Color color)
{
    ? = new SolidColorBrush(color);            
}
```

In main page `.xaml` I have

```
<Grid x:Name="gridColor" Background="{Binding myColor}" />
```

In main page `.cs` I havent nofhing because I dont know how bing color from control page via picker and save it(bind) to panorama main page and change color.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the color picker yet but from what I know of these controls, you could try the Value property of the color picker. Thebn when you navigate to main page, use that Value and pass it to MainPage as a paramater.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?Color="+colorPicker.Value.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
```

Edit:

You also have a Color parmater in picker_ColorChanged. You could also pass that paramater back to MainPage.xaml.

Comment: hm how I can pass parameter Color back to main page?